# Android Google Maps automatic positioning with position deviation

Tags: android

So, dude, I use Google Maps API automatic positioning, I am Chinese Beijing, Spain Barcelona customers, to automatically locate the address I was right in Chinese City, also will not have the deviation, but the customer said in the exhibition that location will have a lot of user location deviation, deviation distance is distance, I do not want to understand why why, automatic positioning will have distance deviation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXVVw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOwBY.png)

Comment: are you using Network_provider ? in determinate location

Comment: post your code of mapactivity

Comment: I have added a picture